# Formulars displayed "raw" in Android App

Tags: support, bug

Mathematic formulars in titles are not displayed correctly in the Android App. Always I see the "raw" code behind it. 
If I switch to view in browser e.g. using Chrome, it works again. 
One example is this [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/37010/is-the-value-of-max-fv-rightarrow-frac-12-frac12-sum-vf)

I am using version 1.0.89 on a Samsung Galaxy S5 mini with Android 5.1.1

Is this known?